# aggregating/summing variables for each ID observations and storing in corresponding new total variables in SAS

Tags: loops, sas, aggregate

so i created a macro for this but issue is i have a lot of variables; more than 50. I was hoping there could be an efficient way to create so i can pass a list of new variables without having to expliclitly call the macro for each variable

```
%macro cal_tot_hit(var, tot_hit);
    (select sum(b.&var)
     from parent_data as b
     where a.ID = b.ID
     and b.&var= 1) as &tot_hit
%mend;

/* call macro */
proc sql;
create table tot_hit as
select a.*,
    %cal_tot_hit(var1, var1_tot_hit), 
    %cal_tot_hit(var2, var2_tot_hit), 
    %cal_tot_hit(var3, var3_tot_hit),
     .......
     .......
     times rest of variables (n=50+ lines)

from parent_data as a
order by a.ID, a.date;
quit;
```

i could create an array of new variables as below too

```
proc sql noprint;
select cats(name,"_total") into :tot_vars separated by " " 
from dictionary.columns  
where
  libname = "work" and memname = "parent_data" 
  and name like 'var_%';
quit;
```

but how can I use an array and a do loop procedure to then subsequently populate these new total variables with the desired sum for each ID where an ID has multiple observations for each date?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do?  It looks like you are actually just COUNTING since you are summing values that are always 1.

Comment: If the question is "how many 1's are there for each variable", you might be better off using PROC FREQ or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is to stop using `PROC SQL`. Other SAS PROCs handle dynamic variable lists much more elegantly. If your variables are all called `VARn` this will do the trick:

```
/* Assuming your input dataset is already sorted by ID. */
proc transpose data=parent_dataset out=long;
   by ID;
   var VAR:;
run;

data summed / view=summed;
   set long;
   array arr_col COL:;
   /* Summing, assuming your VARs are coded 0/1 (otherwise, extend logic). */
   SUM = sum(of arr_col[*]);
   keep ID _NAME_ SUM;
run;

proc transpose data=summed out=wide(drop=_NAME_) suffix=_tot_hit;
   by ID;
   id _NAME_;
   var SUM;
run;

/* Merge back into your parent dataset. */
data want;
   merge parent_dataset wide;
   by ID;
run;
```

Sure, it's a few more steps and you don't have the black magic of the SQL optimizer, but this is *so much more succinct*. Notice how you do not have to be fully explicit about the variables that get summed, or the ones that get merged back - in PROC SQL you would have to be. There's suddenly 10x more `VARn`s? Zero updates needed in this code as long as they follow the naming scheme. Even if they don't, one extra line of code will fix it.

The same applies if you'd want to change the names of your newly created variables - here you just change the `suffix=`, and not the 50+ values you'd otherwise have individually typed out.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the big picture of what you are doing, but yes, the macro language has `%DO` loops so you can pass a list of variables, and have the macro iterate over the list.

```
%macro cal_tot_hit(var=);
  %local i vari ;
  %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&var,%str( ))) ;
    %let vari=%scan(&var,&i,%str( )) ;
    ,(select sum(b.&vari)
     from parent_data as b
     where a.ID = b.ID
     and b.&vari= 1) as &vari._tot_hit
  %end ;
%mend;

%put %cal_tot_hit(var=x y z) ;
```

That macro call will generate code like:

```
,(select sum(b.x) from parent_data as b where a.ID = b.ID and b.x= 1) as x_tot_hit     
,(select sum(b.y) from parent_data as b where a.ID = b.ID and b.y= 1) as y_tot_hit     
,(select sum(b.z) from parent_data as b where a.ID = b.ID and b.z= 1) as z_tot_hit
```

You could use it in your step like (untested):

```
proc sql;
create table tot_hit as
select a.*
    %cal_tot_hit(var=x y z)
from parent_data as a
order by a.ID, a.date;
quit;
```